# How to convert a float date to days and hours

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I have a Dataframe ,you can have it ,by runnnig:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = """
case_id         duration_time  other_column
   3456         1              random value 1
   7891         3              ddd
   1245         0              fdf
   9073         null           111
 """
df= pd.read_csv(StringIO(df.strip()), sep='\s\s+', engine='python')
```

Now I first drop the null rows by using dropna function, then calculate the average value of the left duration_time as average_duration:

```
average_duration=df.duration_time.duration_time.dropna.mean()
```

The output is average_duration:

```
1.3333333333333333
```

My question is how can I convert the result to something similar as:

```
average_duration = '1 day,8 hours'
```

Since 1.33 days is 1 day and 7.92 hours

Answer (score 4):

With [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas), you can use [`timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timedelta.html) :

```
td = pd.Timedelta(days=average_duration)
​
d, h = td.components.days, td.components.hours
```

Output :

```
print("average_duration:", f"{d} day(s), {h} hour(s)")
​
average_duration: 1 day(s), 8 hour(s)
```

*If you need to define the result/string a variable, use this :*

```
average_duration = f"{d} day(s), {h} hour(s)"
```

Answer (score 2):

There are third party libraries that might do a better job, but it is trivial to define your own function:

```
def time_passed(duration: float):
    days = int(duration)
    hours = round((duration - days) * 24)
    return f"{days} days, {hours} hours"


print(time_passed(1.3333333333333333))
```

This should print

```
1 days, 8 hours
```